# Customizing names of controls within a listview generated from a ListItemCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a ListView which has it's table filled out with a ListItemCollection I am creating and managing programmatically.

I want to check which of the controls have received any kind of input, currently I am focused on any kind of TextInput. I do not have any idea how to find exactly which column and row this control is from (by name or id, whichever is easiest).

A solution to this problem in a usual Windows Forms application would be programmatically assigning a unique name to each control. With a template such as `[control name]_[row]`, such as `itemName_1`.

It doesn't seem possible to modify the name of a control generated by a ListItemCollection. I also tried binding a control with `Path="x"`, however XAML prevents using the binding tag with the name property.

What is a good solution to this problem, where I can somehow detect which exact control was interacted with, without searching through all of them?

Here is what I have right now (in the picture only one row was created):
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of this ? Flagging data as "modified" so you can update them in database ?

Comment: That is correct, however I will be updating the "Item Total" and "Sub Total" values. There won't be a database as such, but the data itself will be saved to a human readable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you use WPF in a WinForms way. It's not meant to be used like that, and so you end up doing intricate and bogus things.

Here is what you should do :

Let's say we are manipulating an order containing order details.

We first create classes to hold our data

```
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private readonly ObservableCollection<OrderDetail> m_details = new ...

   public ObservableCollection<OrderDetail> Details { get { return m_details; } }

   public decimal Total {
     get {
       decimal total = 0.0;
       foreach(var detail in m_details) total += detail.SubTotal;
       return total;
     }
   }
}

public class OrderDetail : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private readonly Order m_order;

   public OrderDetail(Order order) {
     m_order = order;
   }       

   private string m_name;
   public string Name
   {
     get { return m_name; }
     set {
       if(m_name != value) {
         m_name = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
       }
     }
   }
   private int m_amount;
   public int Amount {
     get { return m_amount; }
     set {
       if(m_amount != value) {
         m_amount = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Amount");
         RaisePropertyChanged("SubTotal");
         m_order.RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
       }
     }
   }
   private decimal m_unitPrice;
   public decimal UnitPrice {
     get { return m_amount; }
     set {
       if(m_unitPrice!= value) {
         m_unitPrice = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("UnitPrice");
         RaisePropertyChanged("SubTotal");
         m_order.RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
       }
     }
   }
   public decimal SubTotal { get { return Amount * UnitPrice; } }
}
```

And then we gonna create a view to visualize and edit our data

```
...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyOrder}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
      ...
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <TextBlock Text="Total: "/>
  <Textblock Text="{Binding MyOrder.Total}"/>
</StackPanel>
...
```

Comment: How does this help me identify a given control? I am already using binding the "Text" property to a variable. That side of things is already working.

Comment: @AquaGeneral The thing I was trying to explain to you is : in WPF, if at anytime you end up searching for a specific generated control, you're doing something wrong. In this particular case, if you need to do something when data is modified, you must handle it in your "model" or "view model", not in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Knowing that I am simply doing it wrong alone helped, but you also gave more context.